# How to sort a List<Enum, Collection> by order of an enum?

Tags: java, collections, enums

Enum:

```
 public enum ComponentType {
    INSTRUCTION, ACTION, SERVICE, DOMAIN, INTEGRATION,  OTHER, CONTEXT;
 }
```

Class A :

```
 public class A
 {
    String name;
    ComponentType c;
    public A(String name, ComponentType c)
    {
      this.name = name;
      this.c = c;
    }

 }
```

Code:

```
 List<A> l = new ArrayList<A>();
 l.add(new A("ZY", ACTION));  
 l.add(new A("ZY0", INSTRUCTION));  
 l.add(new A("ZY1", DOMAIN));  
 l.add(new A("ZY2", SERVICE));  
 l.add(new A("ZY3", INSTRUCTION));  
 l.add(new A("ZY4", ACTION));
```

How to sort list according to enum order?

Comment: I don't understand what you want... Your example doesn't compile as java.util.List.add doesn't take two object parameters.

Comment: Sorry... I missed the class definition... Just edited. Now, the question is complete

Comment: Do you want it sorted by "ZY", "ZY0" ... or by ACTION, INSTRUCTION ... ?

Comment: Sorted by ACTION, INSTRUCTION .. As the order defined in the ComponentType e.g. INSTRUCTION, ACTION, SERVICE, DOMAIN

Comment: what is result of Collections.sort(list) , I believe it will sort in enum order.

Comment: @SubinS: `Collections.sort(list)` only works if the elements in the list are `Comparable`. Otherwise, you need to provide a `Comparator` yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should simply delegate to the enum `compareTo` method which is already provided and reflects the declaration order (based on the `ordinal` value):

```
Collections.sort(list, (a1, a2) -> a1.getType().compareTo(a2.getType()));
```

Or, if you think that the component type provides the "natural order" for your elements, you can make the A class itself implement `Comparable` and also delegate the `compareTo` method to the `ComponentType` one.

Comment: he wants to do it in Enum order, no need to do the alphabetic order sorting of enum names, just enum order. So wont Collections.sort(list) should work.

Comment: Why did you bring up the "alphabetic order of enum names" ? Is it possible that you commented on the wrong answer (I see there's an other answer that does involve the order you mentioned) ? :)

Comment: Ya I think that was a mistake , i meant some other comment may be. But wont Collections.sort() work?

Comment: Your answer works.. I comment on bellium answer because the output is differed with the question asked.... The bellium answer will be used if the order of sorting is alpahabetically order of ordinal defined in an Enum

Answer (score 3):

Make A implement Comparable. If you want to sort by the names of the enums, use this compareTo method:

```
public int compareTo(A a) {
    return a.c.getName().compareTo(c.getName());
}
```

If you want to sort by the order you have typed your enums, compare the ordinal values:

```
public int compareTo(A a) {
    return a.c.ordinal().compareTo(c.ordinal());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but I couldn't modified my `Enum` class and the order was wrong. That's why I couldn't use simple `compareTo` on enum object. The solution is very simple, just assign the int value for every Enum field and then compare it:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<A> {

    @Override
    public int compare(A o1, A o2) {
        return Integer.compare(getAssignedValue(o1.getComponentType()), getAssignedValue(o2.getComponentType()));
    }

    int getAssignedValue(ComponentType componentType) {
        switch (componentType) {
            case OTHER:
                return 0;
            case CONTEXT:
                return 1;
            case SERVICE:
                return 2;
            case DOMAIN:
                return 3;
            case INTEGRATION:
                return 4;
            case ACTION:
                return 5;
            case INSTRUCTION:
                return 6;
            default:
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        }
    }

}
```

And then:

```
Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [java.util.Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29), one way to do this is:

1. Make `class A` implement the `Comparable` interface, this includes writing a `int compare(A other)` method.
2. Call `Collections.sort(l);`

Answer (score 1):

It appears you should be using an EnumMap as they are naturally sorted by the key.

```
public static void add(Map<ComponentType, List<A>> map, A a) {
    List<A> as = map.get(a.c);
    if(as == null) map.put(a.c, as = new ArrayList<A>());
    as.add(a);
}

Map<ComponentType, List<A>> map = new EnumMap<ComponentType, List<A>>(ComponentType.class);
add(map, new A("ZY", ComponentType.ACTION));
add(map, new A("ZY0", ComponentType.INSTRUCTION));
add(map, new A("ZY1", ComponentType.DOMAIN));
add(map, new A("ZY2", ComponentType.SERVICE));
add(map, new A("ZY3", ComponentType.INSTRUCTION));
add(map, new A("ZY4", ComponentType.ACTION));
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that "ZY" and "ZY0" will get lost as there are other instances with the same type added by this code section.

Comment: True, EnumMap doesn't allow duplicates. Fixed the answer.

Comment: However, given the weird type mentioned in the question title, you may be the closest to the answer; if he actually meant `Map<Enum, Collection>`, then all you need to do is change your `EnumMap` to an `EnumMap<ComponentType, Collection<A>>`

Answer (score 1):

If it is required to sort the class based on ENUM, for consistency purpose we must use the ENUM's compareTo(which if final) method.

Adding this method to A class will help and keep the consistent behaviour.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(A o) {
    return this.c.compareTo(o.c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - start using [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html). So your code woudl be

`List<A> l = new ArrayList<A>();`

And for your question, let your A class implement `Comparable` and override the method compareTo where you can put the expression for sorting. [Example here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Answer (score 0):

Enum compareTo seems to be final and cant be overriden
[Why is compareTo on an Enum final in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519788/why-is-compareto-on-an-enum-final-in-java)

Just do Collections.sort() which will order the list in enum order as you need

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do:

```
    List<A> l = new ArrayList<A>();
    l.add(new A("ZY", ComponentType.ACTION));  
    l.add(new A("ZY0", ComponentType.INSTRUCTION));  
    l.add(new A("ZY1", ComponentType.DOMAIN));  
    l.add(new A("ZY2", ComponentType.SERVICE));  
    l.add(new A("ZY3", ComponentType.INSTRUCTION));  
    l.add(new A("ZY4", ComponentType.ACTION));

    Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<A>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(A o1, A o2)
        {
            return o1.c.toString().compareTo(o2.c.toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have a `List<Enum, Collection>` as this is impossibile, you have a `List<A>` and shoud declare it as follows:

`List<A> list = new LinkedList<>();`

You are trying to instantiate in interface, which is not possible and is a compile time error.

If you want to sort a List of `A`'s you should make a comparable:

`public class A implements Comparable<A>`

and override the `compareTo()` method as follows:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(A other) {
    return c.ordinal() - other.c.ordinal();
}
```

To sort your List you can call:

`Collections.sort(list);`