# Enum used as key in TreeMap not sorted after adding

Tags: java, sorting, enums, hashmap, treemap

I am using a TreeMap, where key is an enum and value is an integer.

```
     TreeMap<Ingredient, Integer> inv;

     public Inventory(){
        inv = new  TreeMap<Ingredient, Integer>();
        inv.put(Ingredient.COFFEE, 10);
        inv.put(Ingredient.DECAF_COFFEE, 10);
        // and so on
     }
```

The Ingredient class is defined as

```
public enum Ingredient {

COFFEE {
    public double getCost() {
        return 0.75;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coffee";
    }
},
DECAF_COFFEE {
    public double getCost() {
        return 0.75;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Decaf Coffee";
    }
},
```

// and so on

However, when i iterate the treemap after adding all the ingredients, the enum keys are not printed in lexicographical order.

If instead of enum it was a class I would be implementing compareto, can i do something similar for enum?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519788/why-is-compareto-on-an-enum-final-in-java

Comment: btw, enums can have fields and constructors and can implement interfaces - you would be better to have a field for cost and a single getCost method declared in the body of the class.

Comment: While it is correct that the `TreeMap` without a comparator uses the natural order of the enum rather than the lexicographical order of whatever property, I don’t get how you noticed. The natural order of the declared constants `Ingredient { COFFEE, DECAF_COFFEE }` matches exactly the lexicographical order as `'C' < 'D'`…

Answer (score 6):

[Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) already implements [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). It uses the order the enum constants are defined in, but sadly you can't override the `compareTo`-method to achieve lexicographical ordering because its is defined as `final`.

But you can [pass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29) a custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to the `TreeMap`.

Comment: I see, so this means, the order i define the enums is not defined in sorted order, that is why the traversal is using the manual order i defined.