# How to properly map this in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, entity, sql-order-by

I have Enum class - Status with three values:
GREEN,
YELLOW,
RED

I also have an entity **SomeThing** with a field of **Status** type. It has **@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)** annotation.

In my DAO with Hibernate criteria I would like to sort through **SomeThing** items ordered by **Status**, but the default order by method is alphabetical (because of **EnumType.STRING**), so I would get **GREEN** items first, then **RED** ones and finally **YELLOW** ones.

But I would like to create a custom order by method. I would like to get **RED** items first, then **GREEN**, then **YELLOW**.

The first idea was to create a dictionary table with **Status** field and and int orderIndex field with OneToMany relationship (one **Status** type, many **SomeThing** records) with **SomeThing** entity. Then I could assign int values to different Status types and then order it by orderIndex field.

What would be the best way to achieve what I need?
Thanks in advance for all your help and input.

Comment: you can simply order them in your getStatus method in SomeThing. order them with, e.g. like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/519844/3959856

Comment: I see what you mean, but the issue really isn't sorting SomeThing by enum type in a custom fashion. The issue is to receive customly (?) sorted collection of SomeThings from the database.This is crucial because I am applying paging and filtering when requesting SomeThing also, so I need to receive already sorted collection, not sort it right after (because it will mess up my paging).

Comment: my bad, I thought you wanted to sort the enums.. well, I guess, since you save status as String you can do in SQL: `FROM SomeThing s ORDER BY s.status DESC` or use Stream API method sorted.